# Retrieve Zabbix Agent Data to C# Program

Tags: c#, asp.net, zabbix, zabbix-api

I'd like to have a web application based on ASP.NET which show the result from Zabbix Monitoring on server ( Windows / Linux ).

So the basic idea is to install Zabbix Agent to specific system and shows the monitoring result to my web application.

How can I retrieve the data from Zabbix Agent and integrate it into my web application?

Comment: I guess you would need to implement the other side of zabbix sender. Looks a bit weird to me. Why not use the work already done and use the zabbix api to grab the items from the zabbix server? Or is this just meant as a coding exercise?

Comment: it was meant to research whether it is possible to have only zabbix agent without its server because os based on windows while zabbix server requires Linux.

Comment: Nice project that would be. In that case it’s smarter to port the server to windows although I think there is a reason why they did not do this years ago. My advice if real monitoring is the goal: add a Linux vm to your network, or a zabbix appliance and use that. Having a bit of proven tech and support ability helps.

Comment: You don't even need to install a linux VM, for testing and small loads you can use the appliance... it's ready to go, just import the OVA in vmware or use any of the available formats